# Updating a range of cells in google sheets when one cell is changed using

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using JavaScript, I want to update a range of cells in Google Sheets.
The code doesn't throw any error, but doesn't work either.

```
function OnEditDate(e){    
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;  
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var act = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var i;
    var j;

    for(i = 2; i = 30; i++){
        for(j = 5; j = 20; j++){
            var newVal = act.getRange(i+1,j).getValue();
            act.getRange(i,j).setValue(newVal);

        }
    }
}
```

This should update all cell in range `E2:U30` by moving the contents of all cells to the left one cell.

Comment: I see a couple of problems now. it should be i, j+1 to pick the column 6 to move data to 5. and there should also be a line to set the value of i, j+1 to null before writing the i,j (newVal) but the code still does not run.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off with a few observations...

**Your for loops are not specified correctly.**

[The for loop syntax is `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax).

Your condition statements are `i = 30` and `j = 20`, which are assignment statements. So in addition to clobbering your intended logic, they also always evaluate to `true`. You should instead be using a comparison operator, something like `i >= 30` and `j >= 30`.

Furthermore, **you shouldn't call API methods such as `getRange()`, `getValue()`, `setValue()` within for loops**. These operations are slow and will cause the script to take a long time to complete.

You should [use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) to get/set the entire range of cells you'd like to update in as few API calls as possible.

In your case, since you're not processing the data, **you have no need to actually loop through the data**.

Here's an implementation that performs the move you described:

```
function moveCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var startingColumn = 5;  // Column E
  var startingRow = 2;  // Row 2
  var numColumns = 17;  // to Column U
  var numRows = 29;  // to Row 30

  // Get the source range which contains the data.
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(startingRow, startingColumn, numRows, numColumns);

  // Get the target range (i.e. same size as sourceRange, but starting one column
  // to the left).
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(startingRow, startingColumn - 1, numRows, numColumns);

  // Get all of the values from sourceRange into a 2-dimensional array.
  var values = sourceRange.getValues();

  // Clear all of the cells in sourceRange.
  sourceRange.clearContent();

  // Set the cell values targetRange, using the values extracted from sourceRange.
  targetRange.setValues(values);
}
```

Note that I'm using the [4 argument version of `getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), which allows you to work with a grid of cells.

Similarly, I'm using [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getvalues) and [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValues(Object)), which allows you to get and set the entire grid of cells in one operation.

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).